# Calculate the decision boundary for Quadratic Discriminant Analysis (QDA)

Tags: machine-learning, discriminant-analysis

I am trying to find a solution to the decision boundary in QDA.  The question was already asked and answered for [LDA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92157/compute-and-graph-the-lda-decision-boundary), and the solution provided by amoeba to compute this using the "standard Gaussian way" worked well.  However, I am applying the same technique for a 2 class, 2 feature QDA and am having trouble.  Would someone be able to check my work and let me know if this approach is correct?

I start-off with the discriminant equation,
$\delta_l = -\frac{1}{2}\log{|\mathbf{\Sigma_i}|}-\frac{1}{2}{\mathbf{(x-\mu_i)'\Sigma^{-1}_i(x - \mu_i)}}+\log{p_i}$

Where $\delta_l$ is the discriminant score for some observation $\mathbf{x}$ belonging to class $l$ which could be 0 or 1 in this 2 class problem.

The decision boundary between $l=0$ and $l=1$ is the vector $\boldsymbol{\vec{x}}$ that satisfies the criteria $\delta_0$ equal to $\delta_1$.  I approach this in the following way:

$$\delta_0=\delta_1$$

Substitute the discriminant equation for both $\delta_0$ and $\delta_1$

$$-\frac{1}{2}\log{|\mathbf{\Sigma_0}|}-\frac{1}{2}{\mathbf{(x-\mu_0)'\Sigma^{-1}_0(x - \mu_0)}}+\log{p_0} = -\frac{1}{2}\log{|\mathbf{\Sigma_1}|}-\frac{1}{2}{\mathbf{(x-\mu_1)'\Sigma^{-1}_1(x - \mu_1)}}+\log{p_1}$$

Algebraic manipulations...

$$\frac{1}{2}{\mathbf{(x-\mu_1)'\Sigma^{-1}_1(x - \mu_1)}}-\frac{1}{2}{\mathbf{(x-\mu_0)'\Sigma^{-1}_0(x - \mu_0)}} = \frac{1}{2}\log{|\mathbf{\Sigma_0}|}-\frac{1}{2}\log{|\mathbf{\Sigma_1}|}+\log{p_1}-\log{p_0}$$

$$\frac{1}{2}({\mathbf{(x-\mu_1)'\Sigma^{-1}_1(x - \mu_1)}}-{\mathbf{(x-\mu_0)'\Sigma^{-1}_0(x - \mu_0)}}) = \frac{1}{2}\log{|\mathbf{\Sigma_0}|}-\frac{1}{2}\log{|\mathbf{\Sigma_1}|}+\log{p_1}-\log{p_0}$$

$${\mathbf{(x-\mu_1)'\Sigma^{-1}_1(x - \mu_1)}}-{\mathbf{(x-\mu_0)'\Sigma^{-1}_0(x - \mu_0)}} = \log{|\mathbf{\Sigma_0}|}-\log{|\mathbf{\Sigma_1}|}+2\log{p_1}-2\log{p_0}$$

The right side of the above equation is a constant that we can assign to the variable $C$ as follows:

$C = \log{|\mathbf{\Sigma_0}|}-\log{|\mathbf{\Sigma_1}|}+2\log{p_1}-2\log{p_0}$

at this point we have:

$${\mathbf{(x-\mu_1)'\Sigma^{-1}_1(x - \mu_1)}}-{\mathbf{(x-\mu_0)'\Sigma^{-1}_0(x - \mu_0)}}=C$$

Next I am trying to solve for the value of y (e.g., feature 2) given some input value of x (feature 1).

To simplify the manipulations, I have temporarily assigned the following variables as: 
$$x_0 = x-\mu_{00}$$
$$y_0 = y-\mu_{01}$$
$$x_1 = x-\mu_{10}$$
$$y_1 = y-\mu_{11}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & y_1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \\ \end{bmatrix} -  \begin{bmatrix} x_0 & y_0 \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} p & q \\ r & s \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_0 \\ y_0 \\ \end{bmatrix} = C$$
$$x_1(ax_1+by_1) + y_1(cx_1+dy_1)-x_0(px_0+qy_0)-y_0(rx_0+sy_0) = C$$
$$ax^2_1+bx_1y_1+cx_1y_1+dy^2_1-px^2_0-qx_0y_0-rx_0y_0-sy^2_0 = C$$
$$bx_1y_1+cx_1y_1+dy^2_1-qx_0y_0-rx_0y_0-sy^2_0 = C-ax^2_1+px^2_0$$
$$dy^2_1-sy^2_0+bx_1y_1+cx_1y_1-qx_0y_0-rx_0y_0 = C-ax^2_1+px^2_0$$
$$dy^2_1-sy^2_0+x_1y_1(b+c)+x_0y_0(-q-r) = C-ax^2_1+px^2_0$$
substituting for $x_0, y_0, x_1, y_1$ we now have the following:
$$d(y-\mu_{11})^2-s( y-\mu_{01})^2+(x-\mu_{10})(y-\mu_{11})(b+c)+(x-\mu_{00})(y-\mu_{01})(-q-r) = C-a(x-\mu_{10})^2+p(x-\mu_{00})^2$$

then I calculated the squares and reduced the terms to the following result:
$$(d-s)y^2+(-2d\mu_{11}+2s\mu_{01}+bx-b\mu_{10}+cx-c\mu_{10}-qx+q\mu_{00}-rx+r\mu_{00})y = C-a(x-\mu_{10})^2+p(x-\mu_{00})^2+b\mu_{11}x+c\mu_{11}x-q\mu_{01}x-r\mu_{01}x+d\mu_{11}^2-s\mu_{01}^2-b\mu_{10}\mu_{11}-c\mu_{10}\mu_{11}+q\mu_{01}\mu_{00}+r\mu_{01}\mu_{00}$$
Finally, I can apply the quadratic formula to solve for $y$ where
$u = d-s$
$v = -2d\mu_{11}+2s\mu_{01}+bx-b\mu_{10}+cx-c\mu_{10}-qx+q\mu_{00}-rx+r\mu_{00}$
$w = C-a(x-\mu_{10})^2+p(x-\mu_{00})^2+b\mu_{11}x+c\mu_{11}x-q\mu_{01}x-r\mu_{01}x+d\mu_{11}^2-s\mu_{01}^2-b\mu_{10}\mu_{11}-c\mu_{10}\mu_{11}+q\mu_{01}\mu_{00}+r\mu_{01}\mu_{00}$

The quadratic formula with these variables would be the following:
$$y = \frac{-v\pm\sqrt{v^2-4uw}}{2u}$$

After attempting to check this solution on a simple data set I obtain poor results.  I cannot figure out if it's the approach to the solution or if something is wrong in my code.

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: there will be plus sign inside the square root in the final roots that you computed which will solve the problem

Comment: It would be much better if you provided a fuller explanation; this requires a lot of work on the reader to check, and in fact without going to a lot of work I can't see why it would be true.

Comment: This is a weak answer.  It does not speak to the question, the method, the motivation.  Could you be more clear, or systematic.  There are guides about what constitutes a fair answer, and this meets none of those.

Comment: Please expand your answer so that it clearly explains your reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the calculations, you will see there are a few bugs in this.

Correct value of w comes out to be : 
$$w = C-a(x-\mu_{10})^2+p(x-\mu_{00})^2+b\mu_{11}x+c\mu_{11}x-q\mu_{01}x-r\mu_{01}x-d\mu_{11}^2+s\mu_{01}^2-b\mu_{10}\mu_{11}-c\mu_{10}\mu_{11}+q\mu_{01}\mu_{00}+r\mu_{01}\mu_{00}
$$

After then the value of y comes out to be:
$$
y = \frac{-v\pm\sqrt{v^2+4uw}}{2u}
$$

After making these two changes, you will get the correct quadratic boundary.