# Contour algorithm - Classification plot

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-visualization, discriminant-analysis

As Amoeba has highlighted in his [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92157/compute-and-graph-the-lda-decision-boundary), the authors of the book [elements of statistical learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn//) make use of a contour algorithm to produce visual plots of classification algorithms.

For example, for their LDA plot on page 111 the footnote mentions the following:

> For this figure and many similar figures in the book we compute the
>   decision bound- aries by an exhaustive contouring method. We compute
>   the decision rule on a fine lattice of points, and then use contouring
>   algorithms to compute the boundaries.

[image]

How would the implementation of such an algorithm work in practice? I would like to reproduce the algorithm in Python for simple cases and any references, examples, or even pseudo-code would be very helpful. Thanks